# I'm not able to use a service principal to configure the Databricks Terraform provider on account-level

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog, terraform-provider-databricks

I want to configure the Databricks Terraform provider to authenticate with the Databricks account API using the `account_id` of a service principal with `account_admin` permissions.
Is there a way to do so as I can't obtain the `account_id` from a service principal. When specifying the application ID of the service principal as the `account_id`, I will get following error messages:

`Error: cannot read metastore: Failed to retrieve tenant ID for given token`

Configuring the provider with an `account_id` from a "real" user with `account_admin` permissions is working though.

Here is my Terraform Databricks provider (account-level) configuration:

```
provider "databricks" {
  alias      = "account-level"
  host       = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use service principal, you need to provide client ID, client secret, and Azure tenant ID (see [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs#authenticating-with-azure-service-principal)). Here is the working example from my code:

```
provider "databricks" {
  host                = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id          = var.account_id
  azure_client_id     = var.client_id
  azure_client_secret = var.client_secret
  azure_tenant_id     = var.tenant_id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I need to use the environment variables `ARM_CLIENT_ID`, `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET`, and `ARM_TENANT_ID` rather than specifying those parameters directly in the provider configuration. So I have added the `auth_type = "azure-client-secret"` to my provider configuration to make sure it will take those environment variables for authentication.

However even with this configuration I get the same error message from above. Do you know what is the problem here?

Comment: Make sure that you use the Application ID of the service principal, not the Object ID... Works just fine for me. Enable logs as described in the troubleshooting guide and see the payload

Comment: So, turns out when I set `account_id = <application_id_of_service_principal>` the Terraform provider will fail to retrieve account level resources. After setting `TF_LOG=TRACE`, I can see that I get a status code 403 Forbidden for all account level resources.

Comment: Actually I have just noticed that the account ID's are the same for every user.
This means it's not a user specific ID but an account console specific ID.
So, the configuration for the Terraform Databricks provider doesn't need any update at all.
But thanks for your help anyway!!